# How do Captcha solving services like 2captcha replicate the recaptcha that a particular user receives

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, grecaptcha

How do Captcha solving services like 2captcha replicate the recaptcha that a particular user receives by getting the site recaptcha key and the URL of the site.

Also can someone help me understand how to the payload of recaptcha works?
[recaptcha payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGlol.png)

Comment: Have you figured it out or not yet?